# Laravel add 30 minutes to created_add for expired

Tags: laravel, timestamp

and I want to show all data in table Transaction using Laravel I'm using `index.blade.php` into Table
so, when someone makes a transaction, I give them 30 mins. example `startTime= 2020-04-26 21:04:00`endTime should be= `2020-04-26 21:34:00`
so when current time= 2020-04-26 21:24:00`, that row will change to yellow
when`current time= 2020-04-26 21:32:00````, that row will change to red
What should I do?

[this is my `index`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80K1Y.jpg)
[this is my `transaction.php`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv6Ec.jpg)
[this is my `transactionController@index`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykAhB.jpg)
[this is my `transactionControlelr@store`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGJ0o.jpg)
[this is my `create table transaction`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4J8E.jpg)

Comment: please copy-paste the relevant parts of the code directly in the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the SO [guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and have a quick read of [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) which contains a checklist of actions to take before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add 30 min to some time just do this:

```
[
    startTime => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    endTime   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+30 minutes'))
]
```

If you need to add 30min to some specific datetime, then use this:

```
$specificDateTime = '2020-04-26 21:32:00';
$increased = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($created_at . '+30 minutes'));
```

Comment: There where you want to add 30min to some datetime. For example you have a datetime `$created_at = '2020-04-26 21:32:00';` And if you want to add 30min just do this:
`$expires_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($created_at . '+30 minutes'));`